# Async component wrapped with suspense warned expecting single root node

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

The route config look like this:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: AboutView
    },
  ]
})
```

HomeView.vue is an async component:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'
import api from '@/api'
import ListItem from '@/components/ListItem.vue';

const articles_from_api = await api.all();
const articles = ref(articles_from_api);

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    Home
    <hr>
    <ListItem v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id" :article="article">
    </ListItem>
  </div>
</template>
```

AboutView.vue is a simple component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    About
  </div>
</template>
```

I use the them in the App.vue:

```js
  <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'home' }">/</RouterLink>
  <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'about' }">/about</RouterLink>

  <RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
    <suspense :timeout="0">
      <template #default>
        <component :is="Component"></component>
      </template>

      <template #fallback>
        <div>Loading...</div>
      </template>
    </suspense>
  </RouterView>
```

But when I run this code, there is a warning:

```
[Vue warn]: <Suspense> slots expect a single root node. 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

But each of the components I use are surely wrapped by a single root node.

I have google the question and find an example that shows how to use suspense with vue-router: [the link is here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/using-suspense-with-router-view-q4nsd?file=%2Fsrc%2Frouter%2Findex.js%3A11%2C4). When I open the the devtools in this website, I also find the same warning. It seems like the example code has same problem, just like mine.

Which thing cause this warning? My vue version is 3.4.

Comment: See https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/560#issuecomment-1457699364 . Looks like a workaround and doesn't explain the problem